# BC Calc AP weird question

Tags: calculus

[Confusing BC problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxSQz.png)

I answered this question as -6, after using u-substitution to solve it. When I checked the answer key, however, it said 6. These answers and questions are straight from previous BC calc AP exams.

I'm not sure where I went wrong with this. Any help would be appreciated.

(Click the link for the image, I'm not sure how to format integrals on this site)

Comment: This is an example of the famous King's Rule, a staple of Indian contest math, which I only found out after browsing this site. If I had to guess, you dropped a $-$ sign somewhere or didn't properly calculate the bounds of integration. In any case, there is no "trick" to this problem. If you do a u-sub correctly, you should get the right answer.

Comment: As to why this works, it captures the intuitive idea that if you flip a function and integrate the same "part" of it, you get the same area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, for example, that we define $f(x) = 2$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Then $f(5-x)$ would also be equal to $2$. Not $-2$.
And integrating from $x=1$ to $x=4$ still gives the result $6$.

This is not any kind of proof of the correct answer, of course,
but in a multiple-choice question like this it is a disproof of all the incorrect answers, which is a useful thing.

Comment: Yes, this is why I deleted the comment. I made an entirely idiotic mistake... It's obviously not reflected over the x-axis.

Comment: Yes, I should have concluded you'd already figured that out yourself. I've trimmed the answer back to just the part that addresses the question.

Comment: (With all the sign changes going on in this problem, though, I wouldn't call it "idiotic" to mistakenly reflect across the wrong line. Just an oopsie.)

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_1^4 f(5-x) \ dx = \int_4^1 f(u) \ (-du) $$
$$= -\left(-\int_1^4 f(u)\ du \right)$$
$$=6$$

Answer (score 0):

When you do a u-substitution under an integral sign, *two* things must be changed accordingly. Namely, the differential must be adjusted and the limits of integration must be adjusted. You get $-6$ instead of $6$ because you only adjusted one of those.

$dx=-du$ and the bounds of $x=1$ to $x=4$ turn into $u=4$ to $u=1$. Notice that the order of the limits changes, though their values did not. Both of these changes have the effect of multiplying by $-1$ and thus cancel out, meaning the answer remains $6$.